# how write a request sql native with springboot 2.1 and java 8?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, mariadb

I am trying to write the following native SQL query, but I have an error that I can not solve.
i would like to write to request sql native ...

i need your help :)

AssignmentDao:

```
``@Repository
public interface AssignmentDao extends JpaRepository<Assignment, Integer> { 
    @Query(value ="SELECT project.PROJECT_NAME, contributor.FIRST_NAME, assignment.START_DATE, assignment.END_DATE from assignment join contributor on assignment.CONTRIBUTOR_id=contributor.id join project on assignment.PROJECT_ID_PROJECT=project.ID_PROJECT", nativeQuery=true)
    List<Assignment> fetchAssignmentDataInnerJoin();
```

AssignmentServiceimpl:

```
@Service("assignmentService")
public class AssignmentServiceImpl implements AssignmentService {
    @Resource
    private AssignmentDao assignmentDao;    
    public List<Assignment> fetchAssignmentDataInnerJoin(){
        List<Assignment> list = assignmentDao.fetchAssignmentDataInnerJoin();
        return list;
```

AppController:

```
    @GetMapping({"/listAssignments"})
    public String listAssignment(ModelMap model) {
        List<Assignment> assignments = assignmentService.fetchAssignmentDataInnerJoin();
        model.addAttribute("assignments", assignments);
        System.out.println("Liste des affectations : " + assignments);
        return "allAssignments";
    }
```

application.properties :

```
# Configurations H2
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
    # Configuration MariaDB
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3308/dbmycapla
    spring.datasource.username=***
    spring.datasource.password=***
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
    #spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
    logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
    logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

And here is the mistake :

```
    org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [SELECT project.PROJECT_NAME, contributor.FIRST_NAME, assignment.START_DATE, assignment.END_DATE from assignment join contributor on assignment.CONTRIBUTOR_id=contributor.id join project on assignment.PROJECT_ID_PROJECT=project.ID_PROJECT]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

    Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: No such column: id_assignment
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

Comment: Can you run that `SELECT` successfully via phpmyadmin or the mysql commandline tool?

Comment: @RickJames , When I run that SELECT via HiediSQL and the mysql commandline tool, the request is successfully ...

Comment: Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @RickJames the result is in a next commentary :)

Comment: @RickJames, i don't understand, if i run that "select * from assignment where id_assignment=1", is success, but if i run "select END_DATE from assignment where id_assignment=1", there is the error.

Answer (score 0):

After the command SHOW CREATE TABLE :

```
assignment | CREATE TABLE `assignment` (
  `id_ASSIGNMENT` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PROJECT_ID_PROJECT` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `CONTRIBUTOR_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `START_DATE` date NOT NULL,
  `END_DATE` date NOT NULL,
  `ASSIGNMENT_RATE` float NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `ACTIVITY` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Texte libre',
  `BILLABLE` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_ASSIGNMENT`,`PROJECT_ID_PROJECT`,`CONTRIBUTOR_id`,`START_DATE`,`END_DATE`),
  KEY `ASSIGNMENT_FKIndex1` (`CONTRIBUTOR_id`),
  KEY `ASSIGNMENT_FKIndex2` (`PROJECT_ID_PROJECT`),
  CONSTRAINT `ASSIGNMENT_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CONTRIBUTOR_id`) REFERENCES `contributor` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `ASSIGNMENT_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`PROJECT_ID_PROJECT`) REFERENCES `project` (`ID_PROJECT`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Comment: It is not normal to combine an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column with other columns in the `PRIMARY KEY`.  A PK is, by definition, unique.  An A_I is, but itself, unique.  Are the other 4 columns unique?